# Are there public domain collections of translations for strings commonly used in software applications?

Tags: internationalization, translation, gettext

It seems to me that there must be some public domain collection of gettext compatible PO files that we could search for 1:1 or fuzzy translations for strings commonly used in software applications?

Is there a technical and copyright friendly way to query services like Google's Translator Toolkit, LaunchPad, Mygengo, etc. to find translations for common strings?

Thank you,
Malcolm

Comment: Launchpad translations are BSD-style licensed and supposed to use only in open-source projects.

Comment: That's an important detail. Thank you Bialix.

Comment: Note that the shorter the string involved, (and thus the more likely it's used in more than one application) the greater the chance that its translation requires some context which is not available. So an automated replacement may lead to translations which are laughable or completely opaque to anyone but bilingual crossword experts.

For example, the correct translation of a button labelled "Close" as in "make this window go away" may be very different from the correct translation of the item "Close" in a drawing app meaning "finish this path by joining the first and last points".

Answer (score 0):

[GAE SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/django/django/conf/locale/) has some 40 or so translated .po files viewable with common words still no 1:1 lowest denominator index